# Android studio не строится приложение с Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

При попытке построить проект в Android Studio, возникает ошибка:

> * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':basicviewsmodule:processDebugResources'.
>   > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Andrey\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Как решить проблему?

Comment: покажите код *build.gradle* из *app* и что установлено в *SDK*

Comment: http://pastebin.com/G2SCvz2C
это в build.gradle

В SDK установлено всё

Comment: тогда попробуйте добавить `compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'` и `ReBuild`

Comment: Всё то же самое.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло

Answer (score 1):

из комментариев, может кому то поможет

1. попробуйте добавить `compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'`
2. `ReBuild` проект